# Rendering problems in Android Studio v 1.1 / 1.2

Tags: android, android-support-library

When I add `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` or another `android.support.v7.widget.*` there are rendering problems.

But *Support Library* is up to date. And I complied in dependecies properly. I can import them in `MainActivity.java`

What is the problem?

Comment: what SDK version did you select for rendering

Comment: Android Sdk Toold v24.1.2. Everythingis up to date. The problem: it can't render in layout android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: the following classes could not be found android.support.v7.widget.toolbar

Comment: What do you mean render problems? Do you mean when you run the app or when you look at the layout via the IDE in "preview"?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I don't know if this will help or not, but I was creating a test project (direct from the wizard, no custom code) and getting this error. Trying to modify the project structure and find the missing class didn't help.

The build failed with the following error:

***rendering problems

The following classes could not be found
**android.support.v7.internal.widget**.ActionBarOverlayLayout***

Obviously it's not the final solution, but changing the Theme in design view from the base "project theme" to anything else allows it to build.

Comment: not is a solution final, but is a good idea :) and works, but How I can fix correctly this error ? anywhere know ?

Comment: I wish I could tell you exactly what it is, but the error persists in Android Studio 1.2. Creating a new project with a blank activity generates the same error as above. It may resolve itself as you begin to actually create a layout, but changing the theme seems like the best way to go to me. Others may think changing the build API is correct, but that's not the solution I prefer.

Comment: I faced a similar issue but when I removed the deprecated ActionBarActivity and instead used AppCompatActivity, then things worked out without any more changes. The [page](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) refers to the changes for v7 appcompat library.

Comment: I am new to working with Android Studio. How do you change the project theme after you have already created the project?

Answer (score 200):

**UPDATE**: Apparently they have fixed this bug in the final Android Studio 1.3 release (according to users reporting this issue solved in the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37043358).

This is a known bug since Android Studio build 1.1, which still exists in AS versions 1.2 and 1.3 beta. Switching the preview's API level from 22 to 21 fixes the for most people. While waiting for a fix you could try it as well.

[image: Android Studio Layout Preview - Switch API to 21]

UPDATE: This is already reported as a known issue of Android Studio (http://tools.android.com/knownissues#TOC-Can-t-Render-Layouts-in-Android-Studio-1.2)

Comment: Also hapens in Eclipse

Comment: @villamejia Does this workaround also fix it in Eclipse?

Comment: @Zhambulable take a look at this answer... i think this should be marked as the correct one (it just makes sense)

Comment: I had exactly the same problem Android Studio 1.2, switching API 22 to API 21 fixed my problem,

Comment: No, this problm still exists in Android Studio 1.4. Any solution?

Comment: @ScottChu is the workaround I described still possible? I'm running on 2.0 preview from Canary and haven't seen the issue for quite a time now.

Comment: Yes! workaround is ok. Just say that issue is not fixed in new version.

Comment: In studio 1.4, if API 23 selected and we use AppTheme, we got rendering problem dialog popup with "class not found" error message of this class: android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar. Switching to API 21 or some other themes resolves the problem. Different class name same problem

Comment: I got the same issue in android 1.5

Answer (score 62):

Possible solutions that worked for me:

1 -> Add the word **Base.** to the beginning of the theme name so that it reads `"Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`

i.e., Change AppTheme parent in **res/values/styles.xml** to resolve this problem.
Replace

> ```
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
>     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
> </style>
> ```

with

> ```
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
>     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
> </style>
> ```

OR

2- > Downgrade API level from 22 to 21 in preview pane as suggested by @david.schreiber

Comment: this fixed the problem for me as well,

Comment: this should have been the selected answer

Answer (score 29):

I changed the AppTheme above the graphical preview to Base.Theme.AppCompat and it disappeared for me. It worked on both 19 and 22 API :) ! Good Luck to all of you!

[image: see what i did]
<sup>click for larger image</sup>

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @LShetty: if i.stack.imgur.com goes down, we're all in a heap of trouble.

Comment: But what if you have your own app theme (which itself has `Base.Theme.AppCompat...` as a parent)? Wouldn't you want to preview how the layout looks with your theme?

Comment: I've been staring at error screens the for months before I found this. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I changed my app theme from "`Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`" to "`Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`"

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem just now in Android Studio 1.2.1.0 with API 22 (Android 5.1.1) selected without changing the theme or API as suggested by others on this thread.

When I updated to the most recent version of Android Studio available via the regular update check,
it works fine now. This shouldn't be a problem in the new version Android Studio 1.2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Change android version from 22 to 21, problem solved, it's the little android icon at top right corner,

Answer (score 1):

Adding to david.schreiber's answer, if you keep your preview in a tight window you may wanna stretch it to access that Android icon.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Android Studio 1.2 as stable version and I have the same problem.

For me the solution was to use the **Canary Channel** and update Android Studio to 1.3.

Now  I have this version and it works perfect but this is not and stable version

[image]

My build.grade is this

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidtest.materialdesign"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing app theme to Base.Theme.App.Compat worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

- Clean project
- Rebuild project
- Sync Gradle