# rendering issue with android API 22

Tags: android, api, android-studio, gradle

When creating a new project in Android Studio while using the latest updates and after adding compile `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0` 
to the dependencies still have this issue (which is solved if I'm using `API 21`):

> Exception Details java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: View_theme   at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ViewUtils.themifyContext(ViewUtils.java:124)   at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.(Toolbar.java:198)   at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.(Toolbar.java:192)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.(BridgeActionBar.java:84)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.(AppCompatActionBar.java:56)

When i opened projects that was originally created with eclipse the rendering for `API 22` worked great on Android Studio .

Can someone please explain this ?

Another issue that i encountered is that when upgrading the SDK it adds the Android M API and it called API 22 just as Android 5.1.1 which can also cause rendering issues . 
The solution is just to switch back to API 22 5.1.1 
Hope it helps .

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, if I'll solve it before you get an answer I'll post it here

Comment: It finally fixed for me after 2-3 gradle syncs

Comment: No change even after another sync

Comment: This link helped me to fix the issue  : 
[Solution to issue][1] (The accepted answer).



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194479/android-studio-rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found

Comment: glad to hear that. I will mark this question as a duplicate then

Comment: see my answer if help you    - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958430/rendering-problems-in-android-studio/29964116#29964116

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958430/rendering-problems-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

**Update :** 
Doing a `Build>Clean Project` or a `gradle Sync Project` will solve the problem.

**Old answer :** 
According to 22.1 changelog ([source](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html)) :

> Lollipop added the ability to overwrite the theme at a view by view level by using the android:theme XML attribute - incredibly useful for things such as dark action bars on light activities. Now, AppCompat **allows you to use android:theme** for Toolbars (deprecating the **app:theme** used previously) and, even better, brings android:theme support to all views on API 11+ devices.

So i guess if you change app:theme to android:theme it will work.

Comment: I have all references as android:theme and still have the same issue

Comment: @BogdanEmilMariesan did you tried to clean project in AS ?

Comment: @BogdanEmilMariesan plz add you layouts files

Answer (score 1):

In my case, solution was as simple as

1. Add `@style` to the parent theme

> ```
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
> ```

2. remove `android.support.v7.widget.` from `Toolbar`
3. move from `app:theme` to `android:theme`

> ```
> <Toolbar
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
>     android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
>     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
> ```

Comment: I've the same issue and also I'm new to android studio. Please could you tell in which file have you applied the above changes? Thanks.

Comment: The first one in styles.xml the rest in every layout you use a Toolbar element