# Android Studio Preview Rendering

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am getting the following error in Android Studio layout preview :

```
Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Fix Build Path, Create Class)
Tip: Try to build the project."
```

I am using **Android Studio 1.3** Preview 3 release.
with 
 buildToolsVersion "21.1.2", com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta1", compileSdkVersion 21.

The App builds successfully and runs perfectly on my phone though. How can solve this issue?
Note that the problem is NOT of instantiation as pointed by the possible duplicate. The issue is only in rendering, the App builds and runs without issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575815/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-v7-widget-too)

Answer (score 1):

Go to styles.xml, you can found there something like

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Darkactionbar">
```

Add "**Base.**" before "*Theme*", to

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Darkactionbar">
```

it's something like a bug in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency for the AppCompat library in your app's `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Note that the version number 22.0.0 depends on the latest support library found in your android sdk for the appCompat library

Comment: Note that the issue is only in rendering.   The app is actually running fine on the phone.

Comment: You may try to rebuild your project then the warning will disappear

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. What worked for me was to change the API to a lower version, I am using the 21 for exemple.
On the layout preview screen, there is a tinny Bugdroid, click on him then choise your API version. you might also want to unclick the *Automically Pick Best* option.
Hope it helped !

Comment: For me it only shows 'API 21', 'Automatically Choose best' and 'Preview Android Versions'

Comment: On your SDK Manager did you checked if all components for API 21 were downloaded ?

Comment: Found a [stack question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29194537/4894540) wich might help ! (even if it has nothing to do with my solution)