# Why is button showing on AVD but not the Designer?

Tags: android

I am very new to android apps, I do mostly VS2013, and I was just trying to do a hello world or anything basic. Why is there a tiny "hello world" on my design for my .xml file, but the button I added shows on the AVD? I'm really confused. [image: Current Desktop]

EDIT: To clarify, this is a brand new project. My question specifically is how can I make sure I can see on the design/text tabs what is going to be on my emulator? All I have done is drag/drop from the Palette onto the screen,and see nothing. What should I be doing instead?

The design device is the same as my AVD.

Comment: Because emulators suck and are not at all reliable in representing how your application will look on an actual device. Run your app on your real device to see actual results

Comment: It's probably just AS's glitch so it just didn't have time to update the layout, because your component tree clearly shows a button, and so does emulator.

Comment: it depends on the device size or dimension you took to preview your layout, there are screen sizes in your preview top tabs tweak them and you will see layout changes, im i lucid enough?

Comment: No, of the two the AVD is the one that is working. How can I see what I add in my design tab?

Comment: have you tried restarting the IDE?

Comment: I'm doing that again now. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't crazy.

Comment: Upon restarting, I get this small warning of "rendering problems": "The following classes could not be found: android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout". I just installed 80% of stuff in the SDK manager. Will this be a problem?

Comment: Started a new project. Went to palette->button->dragged to nexus 4 screen, nothing. I see it in the RelativeLayout and not on the screen.

Comment: Do you see the Android icon in Design tab with number "22", try to change it down to "21" >> see Image http://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Jbr.png

Answer (score 0):

All: The solution was an issue with the rending, and is apparently a bug with the newest version of the Studio. This link I found had the information and solutions to help me with it:

[Rendering problems in Android Studio v 1.1 / 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062658/rendering-problems-in-android-studio-v-1-1-0)