# Layout preview rendering problems in android studio(Android Studio 1.2)

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, renderer

I have the following error in my preview window in the **latest version of Android Studio (1.2)** that stops me from being able to view the layout I am creating, I have tried restarting android studio several times as well as cleaning, rebuilding the project and restarting my computer

EDIT:

Some projects have the same error while other older projects work fine

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
```

**Exception Details**

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:       android/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout$1
    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.<init>(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:177)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:214)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:142)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.<init>(BridgeActionBar.java:84)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.<init>(AppCompatActionBar.java:56)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.createActionBar(RenderSessionImpl.java:1691)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:362)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:497)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:590)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:644)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:586)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:581)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: have you added the support library correct? check these instructions https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: @metaxas4 as far as I am aware yes, the project compiles and runs fine on a device in developer mode, its just the preview where it will not work

Comment: Now in Android Studio 2.3 available in Canary channel you can hide the error window and minimize it permanently. [ Issue 82902: "Rendering Problems" panel can not be hidden permanently](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82902)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try changing your base application theme using below code - in *res/values/styles.xml*

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

**OR**

Also you can try Switching the preview's API level to lower one from the preview configuration

[image]

Comment: Changing from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar then cleaning the project again worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Can tell why this happening ?

Answer (score 4):

You can also update Gradle to version 1.2.3 as explained here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=171417

[Apparently](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=171417#c8) this was a bug on version 1.2.2 of Gradle and from the next version of Android studio Gradle 1.2.3 will be the default on new projects.

At least it worked for.

While Base.Theme.AppCompat.... is the [superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887722/error-rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-suppo/30011016#30011016) of Theme.AppCompat.... anyway, I prefer the fix using the new version of Gradle.

Worked for me, hope it works for you.

Also I had to Clean and Rebuild the Project.

Comment: Didn't work fora me... I tried every fix suggestion in every question -_-'
Don't Google devs use Android Studio to develop? It's still very buggy

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to change the theme of the application by clicking AppTheme.

This does not need to change anything in the code.

I attach the image below

[AppTheme example of solution render problem android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHcF9.png)