# Android Studio 1.5 not rendering layout preview

Tags: android, android-studio

So I'm staring at this image trying to figure out how to actually look at my app...
 
[image]

I just updated my IDE to 1.5 and now none of my projects render a visual representation of their layouts.
I've tried restarting the application, checking for updates, restarting my computer, making sure my SDKs are all in order, but without fail upon startup I am treated to a pleasant view of nothing.

I've tried the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594881/android-studio-not-rendering-layout-preview#comment48324757_26595328) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095839/layout-preview-rendering-problems-in-android-studioandroid-studio-1-2) but nothing has really worked.  I don't see a sort of rendering log or even alerts of bugs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have sdk version 22 installed?

Comment: Mhmm.  I had some issues with 23 so I jumped around to 22, 17 etc.  None of the SDKs are previewing, so I'm trying to reinstall them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-install pretty much all of my SDKs, but I was finally able to get the layout to render again.