# The following classes Cannot instantiate- Recycler view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

In my project. i accidently change the version of recycler view.when i again change that and tried to sync my project.it shows me a rendering problem.i tried clean and reubuild project.invalidate cachy and restart options but no use.someone plz help me....

[image]

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:180)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:118)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.initAutofill(RecyclerView.java:702)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:629)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:601)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:222)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:209)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:544)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:678)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: i am experiencing the exact same problem, have you been able to find a solution i am currenly on  Android Studio 3.1.3
Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.13.0-46-generic

Comment: i found the answer that helped me i.e. look here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095839/layout-preview-rendering-problems-in-android-studioandroid-studio-1-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095839/layout-preview-rendering-problems-in-android-studioandroid-studio-1-2)

Comment: Thanks but i already tried these things.though it shows error my app works perfectly so i not took it as a big issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the version of appcompat you using in your build gradle, I had the same problem using

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

so I just used

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```