# Android Studio 1.2.1.1 layout preview problems

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

After updating to Android Studio 1.2.1.1, I created a new fresh blank project and created a layout.xml

Shortly after creation, I decided to look at the preview. I went in and I saw this:

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in
>   your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the
>   IDE  Exception Details java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
>   initialize class
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.(BridgeActionBar.java:84)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.(AppCompatActionBar.java:56)
>   Copy stack to clipboard

I have never seen it before and I had never encountered it before. 
Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

EDIT:

Someone Recommended me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887722/error-rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-suppo) location but it didn't work. It only brought me `NullPointerExceptions`.

I tried rebuilding the project but it didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR :rendering problems The following classes could not be found android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887722/error-rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-suppo)

Comment: Did you try a `clean` and `rebuild`? Restart the IDE? I just updated as well - no problems yet.

Comment: This often happens when the preview is rendered with API 22, change to lower version and you're good..

Comment: @Lamorak I an using API 22 on nexus 5 for preview. But when i used the following answer, the error was fixed

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems to be a bug. Workaround is to inherit from the `Base` theme in your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Comment: Posted an answer since people don't seem to think this is a duplicate. And since that question doesn't have an accepted answer (just a highly upvoted one...)

Comment: You are right but why does the generated "styles.xml" use `parent="Theme.AppCompact.Light"`? Why didn't google fix it in the update