# I am getting rendering error in the latest android studio when trying to view the preview of an activity

Tags: android, android-studio

Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:

> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open
>   Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

What can be done to solve this? I can't get any preview for my XML coding.

Comment: Post your styles.xml.

Comment: Are you actually using that support library or does it just populate in your Activity (ActionBarActivity or whatever it's called)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio 1.2.1.1 layout preview problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494981/android-studio-1-2-1-1-layout-preview-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens to me too,

the only ways I found to fix this issue is:
at the top of Designer window

1. Change the theme.

OR

2. Change the API to 21 instead of 22.

the second choice is better because you will still able to see the same theme from API 22.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a final solution, but changing the `Theme` in design view from the base `project theme` to anything else allows it to build.

Answer (score 0):

from xml view, check your right side, there was an option for for "Preview"