# I cannot render anything since i install android studio

Tags: android, class, exception, layout, render

I'm new on android studio. I just installed android studio but when I try to create a new proyect the program doesn't shows me the virtual machine. it also shows me a message saying that there's rendering problems.

here's the message. I hope somebody could help me. I will appreciate it

Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
-

```
    android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
     Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr
```

Answer (score -1):

From [ERROR :rendering problems The following classes could not be found android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887722/error-rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-suppo).

> Fix ***res/values/styles.xml*** like so:
>
> ```
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
> ```
>
> Detailed explanation as requested: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` is a subclass of the superclass `Base` anyway. Ctrl+click (Android Studio) on it and you will be taken to the source:
>
> ```
> <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
> ```
>
> We didn't change anything, we just defined it more precisely.