# Android Studio Rendering Problems (No preview)

Tags: android, android-studio, rendering

I have just installed Android Studio and I am a beginner in app programming. I got the following error when I first launched the Android Studio.

```
Rendering problems
The following classes could not be found
- android support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Fix_Build_Path, Edit_XML, Create_Class)
Tip: Try to build the project
```

What might be the cause of this error and how should I fix it?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887722/error-rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-suppo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing AppTheme parent in **res/values/styles.xml** resolved this problem. Replace

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
  </style>
```

with

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Downgrade API level from 22 to 21 in **Preview Pane**

[image]

Comment: Thanks sasikumar, I got to see the Preview clearly now. Really appreciate your help! :D