# Rendering error in Android studio 1.5?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android and recently installed Android Studio 1.5. However I'm getting Some problems in Rendering
[Rendering problem in Android Studio 1.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUUJx.png)
[image]

I've tried installing packages and here are those
[SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejsf8.png)
[image]

I searched forums for help and found some answers. I then selected a lower version of Android API(Android 5.0 instead of Android 6.0). I also tried changing the Theme(Tried Theme.AppCompat, Holo.Light, Material.Light). Then I also edited my styles.xml file in this way

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

instead of

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

I tried every method I found on the Internet, but nothing helped.
The main problem is that I cant See the design interface (or UI, or simply the phone screen) and even if I see it by changing some Settings, I cant add widgets to it and edit the Layout. For example, I cant select the Hello World in default blank activity and delete it.

Friends I am new to Android Development and a very beginner

Comment: What error message do you get? Can you post a screen what you see in the UI editor window?

Comment: most probably it is due to the fact that sdk tools are not downloaded correctly

Comment: I have Put the error message screenshot in a link in Questions. The Link is named Rendering problem in Android Studio 1.5 The error message reads Rendering problems since the following class could not be instantiated - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout and android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Also when i change api, i get another error as android.support.v7.internal.App.WindowDecorActionBar

Answer (score 1):

I changed the android version to use to automatically pick best fit.
It is circled a with blue ink and marked  "x"  in the image.
This resolved the issue for me.

[image]

Comment: Its better is you give some explanation, rather than just a link.  Here you could say: "use the dropdown that I show in this link, since I cant include images yet..."

Comment: Hope this modification is better.

Answer (score 0):

the first answer works for me on android studio 1.5
[ERROR :rendering problems The following classes could not be found android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887722/error-rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-suppo)

- open styles.xml ( app --> res --> values --> styles.xml )
- **remove** existing code in `<style>` tag
- **insert only** this code `<style name="AppTheme"
  parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>`

Comment: I did the same, but didn't help :(

Comment: notice the difference in close tag between `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` and `<style name="AppTheme"
parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>`