# some classes not found in Android 1.3.2

Tags: android

Rendering problem: In android studio 1.3.2 build and create class are not found. how to resolve this problem?

[image]

Is it a measure problem that can make my App fail?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887722/error-rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-suppo

Comment: provide your xml related to this layout