# Why is AppTheme.NoActionBar not working?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-studio-2.0

I've created an Android app in Android Studio, and it has created these styles by default:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

However, in an activity, I try to set this as a theme:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ...
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

But when I run the app I'm getting the action bar:

[image]

Why am I getting an action bar? Am I doing something obviously wrong, or is Android Studio, Google's official IDE for it's own platform, trying to confuse/mislead its developers?

Here is my activity code, there's nothing in it that can cause the action bar to appear by itself:

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    }
}
```

Comment: add `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  </style>
```

and set this as the theme of your activity in the manifest, that is:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Comment: Can you explain why the user's code didn't work as he expected?

Comment: The theme AppTheme.NoActionBar and the elements used in it are activity styling. Applying it to a FrameLayout inside an Activity does not affect the parent activity styling.

Comment: omgggg thank you!!!!!!! I have been searching EVERYWHERE

Answer (score 15):

None of the other answers worked for me, but I found this solution:

Open `values/styles.xml` in Android Studio and change this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

to:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> <!-- changed .DarkActionBar to .NoActionBar -->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you just let Android Studio auto generate the activity, look in `activity_welcome`. There is be `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` and if you delete it, the ActionBar should be gone.

Comment: You saved me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You might have an action bar in your layout, or set theme in AndroidManifest file

Answer (score 2):

Once *WelcomeActivity* extends *AppCompatActivity*, try **Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

If not already done, include a version of appcompat library to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use this theme in manifest.xml, same as:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

And in styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add below

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

You can use

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

You can visit    **[Full Screen Theme for AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompat)**

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the AndroidManifest.xml file. I found that the main theme was established for the app, but the theme I wanted to apply had to be added into the correct activity.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with one of my activities which was not main. I had something like in the Mehmet K's answer as theme:

```
<style name="MyActivitysTheme">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

I just added the parent theme too:

```
<style name="MyActivitysTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

I guess this way it successfully override the main theme

Comment: AppTheme.NoActionBar already declares AppTheme as the parent theme. The period does that