# Android Studio problems loading xml layout view

Tags: java, android, android-xml

I have a problem in Android Studio 2.0.0. The problem is it won't render my xml layout file but it was working the last few months, it did sometimes throw Rendering Problems error but it worked after i press on the refresh button.. now it just doesnt wanna render the scene.. Img with the error is below.

[image]

I tried to click on refresh button, clear cache, restart android studio but nothing seems to be working..

Comment: link may be help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195807/android-studio-rendering-problems

Comment: Try to rebuild your project

Comment: Try to switch  the Theme in the editor to **DeviceDefault**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you post the XML Code we can help you. But as you can see you have a problem with ActionBarOverlayLayout. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887722/error-rendering-problems-the-following-classes-could-not-be-found-android-suppo) is a little help for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean the project and then rebuild it...Most of times this would work.Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working by setting the "Android version when rendering layouts in IDE" to 23...

[image]