# Android Studio: Cannot resolve R

Tags: android

I just installed Android Studio following the steps 1 by 1. All JDK and everything is installed.

I started a new project and created a blank activity and it started off with the error "Cannot resolve R".

I have tried cleaning the project and restarting the program and it did not help.

All the articles and search results I find on this topic say that cleaning the project should fix it. But I'm still stuck. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess it's either:

1. You have no resources (drawables, layouts, etc) in your "res" dir. Workaround: create a dummy strings.xml file or something.
2. Your class' package name is different from your application's package name (in which case, you have to import the R class from com.example.mypackage)

Comment: I checked the res directory and such and did a couple more cleans for good measure. Now it isnt the R that is listed in red, it says that appcompat cannot be resolved. EDIT: And ActionBarActivity

Comment: appcompat is the backwards compatibility library: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat

I think adding `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0` into the dependencies section of your (app) build.gradle should do the trick.

Comment: Ok, I added that to the dependencies. Did a rebuild and a clean. I THINK that the only remaining issue is the ActionBarActivity

Comment: What's the issue with ActionBarActivity? It should've been included with the support library dependency, so it should not be a problem.

It *is* deprecated, though -- the recommendation is to use AppCompatActivity instead. Are you just getting a warning about that?

Comment: (BTW, a tip about asking for help: clear and thorough information will help you get a better answer faster. For example, I wouldn't have had to guess as much or ask for more info if you'd included the exact error message, and perhaps the immediate code surrounding the problem.)

Comment: I apologize: The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout. It says "Rendering Problem" and wont show me the design display.

Comment: That one is new to me, but just googling "android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout" yields [this StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062658/rendering-problems-in-android-studio-v-1-1-0) with a couple of proposed solutions/workarounds. See if any of those fit you.

Comment: I appreciate the help. It seems to have fixed the issue by changine ActionBarActivity to AppCompatActivity and importing it's class.

Answer (score -1):

1. Invalidate cache and restart
2. clean the build

Try to re-run, the app will work smoothly<